# How to utilize a custom tableview cell nib in iOS with a swipe table view controller as the cell's default controller

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am a beginner and I'm having some issues with an iOS app I'm creating. I am utilizing the SwipeCellKit package to have swipeable cells for my tableViews. I would also like to use a custom cell to display birthdays. I created a custom tableView cell and nib. The issue that I'm running into is properly coding the nib into my birthday tableView controller so it will display the information. Below is a picture of my code. I'd really appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction.

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift
import UserNotifications

class BirthdayTableViewController: SwipeTableViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var name: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var birthdayLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var age: UILabel!

let realm = try! Realm()

var birthdays: Results<Birthday>?
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


       
         tableView.register(BirthdayTableViewCell.nib(), forCellReuseIdentifier: BirthdayTableViewCell.identifier)
        
        tableView.rowHeight = 100
        tableView.separatorStyle = .none
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        loadBirthdays()
    }
    
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return birthdays?.count ?? 1
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = super.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAt: indexPath)
            
        
        guard let birthdayCell = (tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! BirthdayTableViewCell) else {fatalError()}

        let birthday = birthdays?[indexPath.row]
        
        let firstName = birthday?.firstName ?? ""
        let lastName = birthday?.lastName ?? ""
        name?.text = firstName + " " + lastName

        if let date = birthday?.birthdate as Date? {
            birthdayLabel?.text = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
        } else {
            birthdayLabel.text = " "
        }
        
        return cell
        
    }

[Beginning of Code][1]
[TableView Methods][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZspG.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IlD1.png
```

Comment: Does it crash the app or it works fine?

Comment: It crashes the app with the code above. if I take out the                                                              guard let birthdayCell = (tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! BirthdayTableViewCell) else {fatalError()} it works fine.

Comment: Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'BirthdayTableViewCell'  . This is the error that I get.

Answer (score 0):

The app crashes due to casting a result of

> tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:for:)

with force unwrap `as!` which returns non optional object.

To solve the error, just change it to `as?`

There is another thing which can lead to an error as well, you typed direct identifier of a cell instead using the identifier `BirthdayTableViewCell.identifier`

```
guard let birthdayCell = (tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: BirthdayTableViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as? BirthdayTableViewCell) else {fatalError()}
```

Comment: Thanks that helped with that error: however, it still doesn't return the any  information in the cell. It returns an empty cell.